# LaTeX warning: font shape undefined but retypesetting works

Tags: fonts, warnings

1. It just started happening this morning without any preamble change.
2. With the warning, some text which previously typeset correctly, now typesets with "changes".
3. Re-typesetting always produces a correct pdf.
4. Closing a correct tex and its pdf and re-opening the tex and therefore the pdf, automatically and *without any typesetting*, produces a pdf with "changes".
5. The "changes" seem to happen randomly:
   Sometimes the "changes" affects \emph, sometimes  \textsf, \textbf, More rarely, even the chapter and section titles,
6. Here is a brand new, minimal tex on the desktop which exhibits the same "changes":

---

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}    

\begin{document}

\colorbox{yellow}{Some Roman text}

\colorbox{yellow}{Some Roman text}

\colorbox{yellow}{\emph{Some Roman emphasized text}}

\colorbox{yellow}{\textsf{Some sansserif text}}

\textsf{\emph{Some emphasized sansserif text}}

\textbf{Some bold text}

\textbf{\emph{Some emphasized bold text}}

asdfasdfasdf

\end{document}
```

7. All that log is saying is "LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted." and, sometimes,

---

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/it' in size <10.95> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/sl' tried instead on input line 15.
```

and here is a "changed" pdf

[image: Screen grab of pdf]

8. Here is the pdf that I get after just re-typesetting:[image: After re-typesetting]
9. I am running a vanilla TeXLive-2013 with TeXShop 2.47 under 10.5.8 on a Dual 1GHz PowerPC G4.

Question: Where should I look?

Very hopeful regards
--schremmer

Comment: `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'OT1/cmss/m/it' in size <10.95> not available
(Font)              Font shape OT1/cmss/m/sl' tried instead on input line 14.` Is expected and not a problem, it isn't clear what else is causing concern?

Comment: The warning is just telling you that there is (not surprisingly) no italic sans serif in computer modern so it is going to use slanted sans serif instead. This is just for information, it is not a problem that needs fixing.

Comment: The font changes. Look at the third line of the pdf. It is not Romam emphasized which should look more like the next to last line.

Comment: no, the third line is italic, the next to last is bold italic

Comment: Or at least that is what I get Yours looks like slanted sans serif? I could add an image to your question to show what I see? I can't add image in comments

Comment: I just found that out and I added to my question the pdf I got after just re-typesetting.

Comment: I can see no way you can get slanted italic sans serif from line 3. If you are lucky someone will recognise the font. Could it be that the font was missing (filesystem problem) and you are seeing your pdf viewer's fallback font? I really can't guess other than "that can't happen" the font warning is line 14 about `\textsf{\emph` and is unrelated to the problem on line 3.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is a rendering issue i.e. it has nothing to do with changes to the PDF. Try deleting font caches. FontBook may be able to do that - I'm not sure. Also, try viewing the PDF in a different viewer and/or on a different machine. But, as David says, what you say is happening is not possible. If you wish to be sure, take an md5sum of the file before quitting the viewer and after reopening.

Comment: I have no idea what happened but, when I started this morning, all was as it should be. I should have tried to restart yesterday and I feel the complete idiot. Very, very apologetic regards.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was an apparently isolated issue solved by restarting the computer.

Comment: I so vote. Apologetic regards